# Enter the workbook name to target sheet in loop

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I have written the below script which will loop through a range of data and copy from one sheet and paste to another, which works fine. I’m now looking to add the workbook name to column D on each row the data is pasted yet all attempts fail.
This is what I’m trying, please help.

```
For i = 6 To LastRow

    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 21) = "OK" And Cells(i, 22) <> "Yes"  Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        erow = Worksheets("iForms").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Worksheets("iForms").Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("iForms").Cells(1, 5).Value = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5)

        If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then Cells(i, 22).Value = "Yes"
        If Cells(i, 22) <> "" Then Cells(i, 23).Value = Time
        If Cells(i, 23) <> "" Then Cells(i, 24).Value = Environ("UserName")
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: `add the workbook name to column D` Then why are you writing to Col E?

Comment: Also to get the workbooks name use this `Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))` Do not hardcode `5`. What if the extension is `.xls`?